# iPhone - trying to create hairlines in quartz

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have this picture, represented in red on the following image. I am trying to create this "hairlines" on the corners of the picture. When printed, the lines are intended to have 1 point of width and 15 points of length.

[image]

this is the code I am using...

1) the first thing I do is to create a context that is 60 points larger horizontally and vertically, so I can draw the black lines.

```
CGFloat newWidth = 60.0f + redImage.size.width;
CGFloat newHeight = 60.0f + redImage.size.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake( newWidth, newHeight),
                                       YES,
                                       [redImage scale]);
```

Then, I define the lines start...

```
NSArray *startOfPoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15, 0)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15 + redImage.size.width, 0.0f)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15, 15 + redImage.size.height)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15 + redImage.size.width, 15 + redImage.size.height)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 15)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15 + redImage.size.width,15)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 15 + redImage.size.height)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15 + redImage.size.width, 
                                                         15 + redImage.size.height)],
                   nil];
```

// these points define, in order, the start of each of the four vertical line and the start of each of the horizontal lines

Then, I draw the lines

```
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// go to the beginning of each vertical line and draw the line down
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        CGPoint aPoint = [[startOfPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1.0f);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, aPoint.x, aPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, aPoint.x, aPoint.y + 15.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
    }

// go to the beginning of each horizontal line and draw the line right
    for (int i=5; i<9; i++) {
        CGPoint aPoint = [[startOfPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1.0f);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, aPoint.x, aPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, aPoint.x + 15.0f, aPoint.y );
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
    }
```

but I end with a huge black square...

what am I missing?

NOTE: this code doesn't show the red image being drawn, this because I want to get the lines right. I am obtaining a huge black square, instead of the lines. The huge square has the size of the context and is the same I would obtain if I simply create the context and fill it with black... :(

Comment: What do you do after the end of this drawing code? You're doing all this in a new image graphics context, when do you get the image out of it to display on the screen?

Comment: I don't display on the screen, I just print. The shown code should show the lines without the image, because I have disabled the drawing of the image until I get this right, but as I said, I get a huge black square, the same I would obtain by just creating the large context and fill it with black. No lines... amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a bitmap graphics context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, every pixel in the bitmap is initialized to all zeros, which is black (if you set `opaque` to YES, which you did) or transparent (if you set `opaque` to NO).

You can fill the bitmap with white before drawing anything else by doing this right after `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` returns:

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
```